# How to write the same NSString to a plist multiple times. With overwriting iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, xcode, plist

I am writing a tweak for jailbroken iOS devices and I want to be able to write this `NSString` "bundleID" and the integer created in my code to a plist file. The code below can do this, however, it only does this once and doesn't allow me to write it to the plist multiple times. I want to do this because the bundleID changes and should also be written to the plist. Basically what I want to do is when an app is launch the bundle id for that app (com.apple.mobilesafari) is written as the key in my plist. I then have code to work add 1 to the value every time the app is opened. So for example if I opened mobile safari four times the plist should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"          "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.mobilesafari</key>
    <integer>4</integer>
    <key>customText</key>
    <false/>
    <key>enabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, when I launch mobile safari four times it stays as...

```
<key>com.apple.mobilesafari</key> <integer>1</integer>
```

I also want the bundleID saved for every app. So if I open safari then contacts I want both in my plist. For example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.mobilesafari</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>customText</key>
    <false/>
    <key>enabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.contacts</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>customText</key>
    <false/>
    <key>enabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is my objective-c code...

```
%hook SBApplicationIcon
-(void)launch
{
// Return original method
        %orig;

// Get Bundle ID
    NSString* bundleID = [self leafIdentifier];

// Print that badboy!
    NSLog(@"Bundle ID: %@ ",bundleID);


// Set up plist
NSMutableDictionary *launches = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]     initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.bengerard.ipslider.plist"];

// Check plist exists
NSString *pathToFile = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.bengerard.apppop.plist";
BOOL isFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathToFile isDirectory:NO];

 if(isFile)
{
// Counting
    int count = [[launches objectForKey:bundleID] intValue];
    count++;



// Write number of launches to plist
    [launches setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:bundleID];
//[launches insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:bundleID];
    [launches writeToFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.bengerard.apppop.plist" atomically:YES];

}
else {
//The file doesn't exit. 
}
// [bundleID release];
// [pathToFile release];
// [launches release];

}
%end
```

P.S: I am also using theos by DHowett to compile my tweak.

**Edit: Realised my two plists are different. Probably causing my problem. I will test later**

Comment: Also note that there may be a difference between launching an app and merely bringing it to the foreground.

Comment: Well the code does work. However, just won't write to the plist multiple objects